# Finding Light Spots with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to circle all light spots with opencv. The Idea is to find with a webcam the light spots, so if I have 3 LEDs in the scene I would likt to circle them. But I am not sure how to circle/filter them. Here is my code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)


    (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(blur)


    hi, threshold = cv2.threshold(blur, maxVal-20, 230, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    thr = threshold.copy()


    cv2.resize(thr, (300,300))


    edged = cv2.Canny(threshold, 50, 150)
    _, lightcontours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)





    for (i, c) in enumerate(lightcontours):
        points = []
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),
            (0, 0, 255), 3)
        points.append([[int(cX), int(cY)]])
        print points
        cv2.putText(frame, "#{}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)


    cv2.imshow('light', thr)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('edges', edged)
    cv2.waitKey(4)
    key = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So what can I do to circle them? I found some sources where they circle light spots in a picture but did not managed to adapt them for streaming. Any ideas?

Best regards

**UPDATE**:
I updated my code to show the actual state.

Comment: You just have to **draw** the found contours on the frame

Comment: yes, draw onto the 'frame' image, then imshow it, and remove the 'waitKey' statements.  or create a new video by writing each frame as you process it.

Comment: @potu1304 Did you give it a try?

Comment: That worked very well! I see the contours better now, but how can I "simply" circle them to have for example a red circle around the brightest spot?

Comment: @potu1304  You can use the contour properties again

Comment: @potu1304 Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thank you, I build a for loop and enumerate over the lightcontours. I wonder if there is a way to get the coordinates from this circles? Is there a way?